# ag-Grid change autoHeight of columns programmatically

Tags: html, angular, ag-grid

Hi is there a way to call the function that they use in autoHeight of Column Definitions? I have a function that Expand and Collapse the row based on the content of one column which is remarks. On the initial load the row height is fix for 2 text lines only. And when I click the Expand the row will expand depending on the remarks column content. Their autoHeight is working on initial load to expand the row base on the content but I do not need it on initial load. When I try to update it upon clicking Expand button then calling the resetRowHeights nothing happens. I have a temporary solution which I compute the length of the text, etc. It works on normal scenario but the problem is if they change the width of the column into smaller then expand. I try to get the ratio of text to column to dynamically compute it but the computation failed.

Below is my current code for computing the rows.

```
expandView() {
        this.isExpand = true;

        this.gridApi.forEachNode((rowNode: RowNode) => {
            let ulRemarksTotalRowHeight = 0;
            let customerRemarksTotalRowHeight = 0;
            let ulRemarksList = [];
            let customerRemarksList = [];

            const ulRemarks = rowNode.data.map_ul_remarks;
            const customerRemarks = rowNode.data.map_cust_remarks;

            if (ulRemarks) {
                ulRemarksList = rowNode.data.map_ul_remarks.split('\n');
            }

            if (customerRemarks) {
                customerRemarksList = rowNode.data.map_cust_remarks.split('\n');
            }

            if (ulRemarksList) {
                for (let i = 0; i < ulRemarksList.length; i++) {
                    const display = ulRemarksList[i];

                    // 28 - Default height value(in px) of one row in ag-Grid;
                    // 19 - Maximum text length for one row in ag-Grid(Initial Load/Without Resizing the Column of UL and Customer Remarks);
                    const ulRemarksHeight = Math.ceil(display.length / 19) * 28;
                    ulRemarksTotalRowHeight += ulRemarksHeight;
                }
            }

            if (customerRemarksList) {
                for (let i = 0; i < customerRemarksList.length; i++) {
                    const display = customerRemarksList[i];

                    // 28 - Default height value(in px) of one row in ag-Grid;
                    // 19 - Maximum text length for one row in ag-Grid(Initial Load/Without Resizing the Column of UL and Customer Remarks);
                    const customerRemarksHeight = Math.ceil(display.length / 19) * 28;
                    customerRemarksTotalRowHeight += customerRemarksHeight;
                }
            }

            const largestHeight = Math.max(ulRemarksTotalRowHeight, customerRemarksTotalRowHeight);

            if (largestHeight !== 0 && largestHeight > 56) {
                rowNode.setRowHeight(largestHeight);
            } else {
                // 2 rows = 56px;
                rowNode.setRowHeight(56);
            }
        });
        this.gridApi.onRowHeightChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Well for me, I do not need `this.gridApi.onSortChanged();` because the sort is functioning the same even if I expand or collapse the rows.